# How the orbit of Earth changes if it has the double of water in the ocean?

Tags: magic, alternate-reality, ocean, water-bodies

A portal to another Earth in a parallel universe is open at the bottom of the Ocean and all the water is moving to the new Earth in the form of a waterfall in the middle of the Atlantic. The form of new Earth is exactly like ours.

- Is the orbit of the planet affected?

My focus is on this new Earth status, more than how the people react to this magic.

Comment: Please, one question per post, with enough information to answer it. I count 4 questions here.

Comment: IMO 3 of the questions are connected with each other. Only the 4th question may differ.

Comment: Also, your question is not clear. The water is going from *this* Earth to the new planet, which was already Earth-like (so is, 4/5 covered in water)? Are you interested in the changes of that new Earth, on this Earth, on both?

Comment: Edited to fit. I will create more questions.

Comment: Your last edit added a completely different question again, one that is effectively too broad as it is. Effects on climate due to such massive changes are nearly impossible to calculate.

Comment: You are right, I would stay with only orbit.

Comment: What would be the momentum of this magically created water? Will it start as moving in the same way the rest of Earth is, or immobile in respect to the Sun, or what?

Comment: Same way as the rest of Earth.

Comment: Why is this question too broad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation for the orbital period of a body around a center of mass comes from Kepler's third law:

$$T^2GM=4^2R^3$$

Where T is the period, G is the gravitational constant, M is the sum of the masses involved, and R is the mean distance from the center of mass.

If you increase a body's mass, you will either reduce the orbital period, increase the mean distance from the center, or a mix of both.

The masses involved are one sun, one Earth, and one set of oceans.

Sun: ~$2 \times 10^{33}g = 2,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000g$
Earth: ~$6 \times 10^{27}g = 6,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000g$
Oceans: ~$1.4 \times 10^{24}g = 1,400,000,000,000,000,000,000,000g$

So you are increasing mass by:

$$(1 - \frac{2,000,006,001,400,000,000,000,000,000,000,000}{2,000,006,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000}) \times 100 = 0.0000000007\%$$

So supposing we keep the mean distance from Earth to the sun, the orbital period goes down by the square root of 0.0000000007 percent. The year will last approximately 0.0006 seconds longer.

If instead we keep the orbital period, the mean distance from the Earth to the barycenter by the core of sun will be reduced a little, but that wouldn't impact seasons.

What would impact seasons would be the fact that there would be a flood of biblical proportions. I don't know how to calculate how much the sea level would go up, but consider this: just three of four meters upwards is enough to flood most coastal cities of the world. That won't be nice to anyone.